# Progress Bar Color

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I have the following codes

HTML:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="progressBar">
   <div class="progressBarIndicator">
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.progressBar{background-color: #fff; height:20px;}
.progressBarIndicator{background-color: #000; height:20px;}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.progressBarIndicator').css("background", "red");
});
```

It is not working on my application.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojeYmE)

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working': http://jsfiddle.net/y8vo94of/

Comment: the color of the progress bar is not changed to red

Comment: is there any external js file which needs to be include in your html page?

Comment: i already checked it, but not more extra js file i need

Comment: try `$('.progressBarIndicator').css("background-color", "red");`

Comment: could you try to put an alert inside the `.ready` function to check if your jquery really works.. `$(document).ready(function(){
   alert('test');
});`

Comment: @DyrandzFamador it's work for alert

Comment: try this one maybe you have other function that prevents to override its color:  `$(".progressBarIndicator").css("cssText", "background: red !important;");`

Comment: @DyrandzFamador I think so, but its color still remain the same

Comment: may be because you didn't add any width to it?

Comment: @WisdmLabs width is added too

Comment: can you please post the whole css(for both the classes), if alert is working then there might be a mistake in css

Comment: .progressBar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(199, 197, 197, 1);
}

.progressBarIndicator{
  height: 20px;
  background: #019F45;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
}

here my css codes for this progress bar

Comment: you didn't add width in .progressBarIndicator class add width .progressBarIndicator { width:40%; }

Comment: @WisdmLabs no, the width i added in the html file; it is dynamic progressbar

Comment: i tried to change the color for div 
{$(document).ready(function(){$('div').css("background","red");});}

the div is worked

Comment: please edit and add more of your code for progress bar for all the 3, html,css and jquery. this code is too little to understand the problem